# Android Studio Error When Trying To Use AdMob (Crashes When Run)

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with my app after pressing the run button and directing it to my adb device (HTC One M9 Plus running 2.30.401.1, Android 6.0 if you don't know HTC version numbers, if it makes any difference).

Here is the logcat log from Android Studio

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1515)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6100)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:859)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' 
on a null object reference
at com.groverstudios.applestore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1131)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2564)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1515) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6100) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at co m.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:859) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance :)

Comment: NPE ??, show some code snippet so that we can find why/where NPE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says quite clear what is happening

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
```

So you have a member or variable pointing to an `AdView` and this is null.
You need to do a `.findViewById(R.id.name_of_your_adview)` before you call the `.loadAd(...)` method.

Comment: Accepting an answer is a nice way to say thank you :) - Glad I could help!